# Encrypted push notifications in Swift sent through Firebase Functions

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, encryption, google-cloud-functions

I'm using `AES-256` encryption on a chat messages in my app. The messages are stored in `Firebase Firestore` and a function in `Firebase Functions` sends out a push notification upon new messages.

Since the string is encrypted, the push notifications of-course looks weird. I'm decrypting the messages within the app, but how can i decrypt the messages if the app is closed or terminated? I have looked into two options.

### Handling it on the device

Can I decrypt the string before it is being presented as a push notification through the `AppDelegate`? *If so* under which function?

### Handling it on the Firebase Functions

Should I decrypt the messages in `NodeJS` function? Is this a recommended way? There seems to be a lot of different libraries in `NodeJS` for `AES` decryption, any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `Push Notification Extension`. Decryption of text is actually used as an example for this type of extension [by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications).

After you add a new target (extension) to your app, Xcode will automatically create a base class for Notification service extension.

It will have method:

```
func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
```

So decrypting would be quite straightforward:

```
var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest,
                         withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        if let body = decryptBody(userInfo: bestAttemptContent.userInfo) {
            bestAttemptContent.body = body
        } else {
            bestAttemptContent.body = "Encrypted"
        }

        if let title = decryptBody(userInfo: bestAttemptContent.userInfo) {
            bestAttemptContent.title = title
        } else {
            bestAttemptContent.title = "Encrypted"
        }

        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}

func decryptBody(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> String? {
   //Decrypt
}

func decryptTitle(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> String? {
   //Decrypt
}
```